# Check if Form is in bounds of all screens

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to elaborate if the complete form is visible on screen. To clarify this: I don't care if the form is partially or fully hidden by another form, I just want to know, if the form is completely on the screen.

In Windows it is possible to move forms around, such that they are hidden half way. That is because you can move them past the actual bounds of any monitor. (Further to the left, right or bottom.) How can I check if that is the case in an easy way?

What I figured I could do is to check if the form is in bounds of `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen`. The problem here is, that not every pixel of the virtual screen is actually visible. Of course this would work if `SystemInformation.MonitorCount = 1`

Still I'm not really happy with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way I can think of is that you check that all four corners of the form are on a screen.  Like this:

```
    public bool FormOnScreen(Form frm) {
        if (frm.IsHandleCreated) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (!frm.Visible || frm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) return false;
        return PointVisible(new Point(frm.Left, frm.Top)) &&
               PointVisible(new Point(frm.Right, frm.Top)) &&
               PointVisible(new Point(frm.Right, frm.Bottom)) &&
               PointVisible(new Point(frm.Left, frm.Bottom));
    }

    private static bool PointVisible(Point p) {
        var scr = Screen.FromPoint(p);
        return scr.Bounds.Contains(p);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I just have to construct an obscure example here. Imagine three monitors aligned beside each other, each 800px wide. Monitor 1 and 3 are 600px high, monitor 2 (the one in the middle) is 400px high. The virtual screen real estate would be 1800px*600px. If monitor 2 would be aligned on the top of the other monitors, then there would be 200px on the bottom of the virtual screen real estate which wouldn't be visible. Now I could span a window from monitor 1 to monitor 3 and the whole form wouldn't be visible, the bottom would be missed on monitor 2.

Comment: Well, you'll need to write a lot more code to handle such a case.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I know, it was just a very constructed example. I hope that it'll never come to that.

Answer (score 5):

```
Public Function IsOnScreen(ByVal form As Form) As Boolean
    Dim screens() As Screen = Screen.AllScreens

    For Each scrn As Screen In screens
        Dim formRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(form.Left, form.Top, form.Width, form.Height)

        If scrn.WorkingArea.Contains(formRectangle) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Why on Earth are you using DoEvents?

Comment: Returns `False` if the window is maximized.